# asyncTask in android for retrieving data from MySQL database

Tags: php, android, html, mysql, android-asynctask

Please I have set up my wampserver and configure my android device over wifi to access the database and server correctly and it is working well. I want to select data from the database in the wampserver and display the data in a TextView and I am using an asyncTask to perform this operation which seems to be working.Now the problem is the results.  I have tried several  options to manipulate this yet I am still getting "
" a line break in the TextView or Toast msg. I can figure out why I am still getting this a return. Any assistance will be very appreciated.Thank you

```
     class SingmeIn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try{
                String username = u;
                String password = p;
                String link = "http://192.168.30.1/androidphp/loginget.php?username=" +username+"&password="+password;
                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(link));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
               (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
               String line="";
               String[] data=null;         
               while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                   data=line;
                  break;
                }
                in.close();
                return data[0];   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

     }
    @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result){
          //statusField.setText("Login Successful");
         role.setText(result);
         //System.out.println(result);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
}
```

This is my PHP code :

```
       <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("192.168.30.1","root"," ","searchmedb");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT UserType FROM accounts where    UserName='$username'                  and UserPassword='$password'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $data = $row[0];
    if($data){
    echo $data;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Initially I was using this in my while loop, which did not also work:

```
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line +"\n");
                  break;
                }
                in.close();
                return sb.toString();
```

Comment: what are you getting exactly? Be clear

Comment: All i get after a button click is <br/>

Comment: can you make sure your php code is returning something? by checking that in your browser before using in android?

Comment: Please,I have checked now and my php code is working

Comment: try one thing, in your PHP code you are getting $_POST[] variable while in your android you have done the coding for GET method, make that correct

Comment: Now I think the error has to do with $_POST[username] and $_POST[password], I does not recognise them and it says undefined username on that line inside my php file. When I change it and put in the static actual values i am submitting through the TextView textbox it works.

Answer (score 0):

You PHP code returning some additional space. Check at the end of the line of your php file.

Comment: No, I don't think so, I have just test the php code against that and it returns the value I want in the browser for , but it doesn't in the android

Comment: trim() the returning content!

Comment: I just realise in my logCat this is what I get as results after execution 05-22 19:45:04.642: D/result SS(6578): <br /><font size='1'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\androidphp\loginpost.php on line <i>8</i></th></tr><tr>align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0232</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>252616</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\androidphp\loginpost.php'

Comment: I am getting some html tags , this is very strange for me, I seem to have little idea on why this is happening

Comment: Hey! i found the issue. Your calling from Android code through GET request. But your using $_POST in php. Seems not perfect. Change $_POST to $_GET in php. This will fix the bug for time being.

But for Best solution,  Make Httppost call on Android, And in php receive value i using $_POST. Username & password are Confidential. it should not in GET

Comment: Problem solved, it was an indication of an error message from mySQL.